# Ionic 4 - Rendertron not rendering web components

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, server-side-rendering, rendertron

I am using Ionic 4 alongside with Angular 8 and Rendertron.

Unfortunately Rendertron cannot handle Shadow DOM and Ionic fully depends on them. Shadow Dom is completely missing when rendered via Rendertron (this is what I expect), but also the web components do not contain any stylings, logic, etc.

I already tried ShadyDom, Webcomponentjs, severall other polyfills. None of them do work. I tried with another project (Angular with Material w/o Ionic) and it works like charm. Seems like they are working for own defined web components but not for Ionic Web Components.

> Sources
>   https://github.com/webcomponents/polyfills/tree/master/packages/webcomponentsjs
>   https://github.com/webcomponents/shadydom

**Is there an existing solution of getting Rendertron work with Ionic?**

Short Example when I use Rendertron alongside with or without polyfills (does not matter):

```
<!--Ionic Output-->
<ion-button routerLink="/internal-link">My Button</ion-button>

<!--Rendertron Output (exact the same, Rendertron does not change the Web Component)-->
<ion-button routerLink="/internal-link">My Button</ion-button>

<!--Rendertron Output (what I would expect)-->
<a href="/internal-link">
  <button class="some-polyfilled-class">My Button</button>
</a>
```

Very thanks :)
Karsten